# Why are image links by the editor not inline?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, markdown, editor, images

I see that image links have the URL at the bottom, which may confuse new users, and has become [a minor nuisance](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4140/why-are-users-removing-image-urls-and-leaving-the-image-tag) at Ask Ubuntu, leaving unhandleable (due to the URL being lost) problems.

Is the putting of image links at the bottom by design, or is it something that the developers can and will tweak?

Comment: Hi, I noticed you deleted your answer in Meta AU after my comment, that wasn't my intention, it was a good answer pointing to another good answer, my (nitpickish) issue was with the phrasing that suggested this was policy.

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm sorry. I may have misunderstood you. Now, the answer reains, but is not official policy.

Comment: No worries. To clarify what I meant by my comment there: kiamlaluno's answer is a good one, one that I agree with, but far from "official policy". Even if it was official policy, AU, as any SE site, can still treat it as a suggestion / guideline. Your own Meta is where you decide your site's official policy, not MSO. If the AU community likes your answer there and decides to follow the advice given, that would be the official policy for AU then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The links could be inlined, as you originally wrote the link to the question on the meta for Ask Ubuntu, and that would not create any particular issues with the post.

I am with Alenanno when he says the other link style is preferable, but I would make also another consideration: Those users don't even notice the image doesn't appear in the post.
There is the preview of the post they are writing; they see the post as it appears to the other users when they save it; still, they don't notice the image is missing. In other words, they don't put much effort in writing the question.

What can be done in those cases is closing the question as too localized, if the question heavily depends on the image. I don't see any reason to change the way Stack Exchange sites work, for users who (as you said) just ask one-two questions, and then don't return anymore to the site.

Answer (score 6):

I want to go ahead and say: what's the difference between this and normal links?

I mean, when you edit you need to be careful of any link, not just image links. It's a problem of being careful to those links in general, rather than a problem with images.

Personally I prefer this linking way, because the links are below and they don't clutter the editing part. An example taking your link from the question. When I edit, reading something like:

> [...] which may confuse new users, and has become `[a minor nuisance](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4140/why-are-users-removing-image-urls-and-leaving-the-image-tag)` at Ask Ubuntu, leaving unhandleable (due to the URL being lost) problems.

is way more confusing than

> [...] which may confuse new users, and has become `[a minor nuisance][1]` at Ask Ubuntu, leaving unhandleable (due to the URL being lost) problems.

It's far more readable and I don't need to lose myself in weird links. But I can see it's a personal preference.

Going back to your question, I think that a more appropriate plan would be to **educate new users** rather than changing just one link style when there is no difference in my opinion.

Comment: Our problem at AU is really that there are so many unregistered users that come for one or two questions (and many of them fail to read the FAQ) so educating them would be prohibitive. Also the loss of the links is not due to sloppy editing, as often the first revision would have already lost the link due to the OP not understanding it is needed for the image, which is understandable, given the OP may be currently having a failing system and needing answers quickly, causing stress.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS If unregistered users edit, it means that someone is accepting their edits. Who accepts edits without checking them first?

Comment: They're not edits. It appears in original, unedited posts, many of which have not been edited at all. If the OP removes the image link, then nobody can rally find the image, and so are powerless to get the OP's screenshot, bootchart, etc

Comment: +1, because of "they don't clutter the editing part". Re-editing those post may become a nightmare sometimes